# Odata equivalent to MySQL query or Mapping of SQL query to OData one

Tags: odata

What is Odata equivalent to following mysql keyword or usage

1. distinct
2. join/inner join
3. left join/left outer join
4. right join/right outer join
5. full join/full outer join
6. like operator
7. min/max operator of a column
8. rownum or rowcount comparison
9. group by
10. having count() and exists()

How to use $expand with respect to join or left outer join in mysql?

Is there is any plugin or tool available which does mapping of SQL query to OData one? Or Conversion of MySQL query to Odata

Thanks